# smoothly bridge loop edge

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm new to Blender. I'm learning bridge edge loop.

I want to bridge two circle, because the number of verts of the circles is different, there are many triangle face that cause unevenness. I use alt+j to convert Tris to Quads but is works not so well

you can get my file from [image]

I hope this surface doesn't have too many corners like the picture
[image]

Comment: in order to avoid tris you could give the same amount of vertices to both the 2 edge loops, select the bottom one and X > Limited Dissolve with an angle of 13.2 to get 49 vertices, then Ctrl E > bridge edge loops, shade smooth and maybe give it a Subdivision Surface modifier?

Comment: @moonboots wow, thanks, it works vert well. and could you tell me how can you get the  angle of 13.2? I want to try to generalize this operation

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I just tested the angle that would leave 49 vertices and it was 13.2 (in the Operator Box)

Comment: @moonboots because this operation will appear many times and the number of vertices is not the same, so i hope the angle can be calculated so that i can code a python script to do it, Anyway, thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has the expected limitations of non-adaptive resampling, but, if bridging unmatched profiles  is a frequent operation, you might consider adding a simple Geometry Nodes Tool...

[image]

.. which resamples your mesh profiles to your given resolution, by converting to a curve, and back again.

In this example file, added as a local tool asset to the Header > Mesh menu:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

in order to avoid tris you could give the same amount of vertices to both the 2 edge loops, select the bottom one and <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* with an angle of 13.2 in the *Operator Box* to get 49 vertices, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*, shade smooth and maybe give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier.

[image]

To display the amount of vertices enable *Statistics* in the *Viewport Overlays*:

[image]

Result:

[image]