# How to add geometry nodes with python

Tags: python

I create a modifiers who's type is NODES, and run bpy.ops.node.new_geometry_node_group_assign() to create a geometry node groups

but when i run bpy.ops.node.add_node(use_transform=True, type="GeometryNodeMeshToCurve")

it throw RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.node.add_node.poll() failed, context is incorrect

beacuse of some reason, I can't open Node Editor window.

Is there a method to implement this operation?

For specific geometry nodes tool，please refer to the second answer to my previous question
[smoothly bridge loop edge](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/313750/smoothly-bridge-loop-edge/313763#313763)

the code i create modifiers and node groups:

```
obj = bpy.context.active_object

modifier = obj.modifiers.new(name="Resample", type='NODES')
bpy.ops.node.new_geometry_node_group_assign()
```

Comment: Don't use operators when non-operator API exists. See my answers: [here - Blender 3.6](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/289622/60486) and [here - Blender 4](https://blender.stackexchange.com/revisions/313554/3)